# noclassdeffounderror this is error

Tags: java, android

```
package connection;

public class NewTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements ActivitySorter{

 private XMPPClient MainActivity;
 private XMPPConnection setConnection;
 public static XMPPConnection connection;
 private Context context;
 public String payload = "<question id='56 'text='Favorite Food'><option id='1'>chinese</option><option id='2'>indian</option><option id='3'>thai</option>";
 private Activity activity;
 public static String payload_data = "";
 public NewTask(Context context)
 {
     this.context=context;
 }

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

  ServiceProviders.Register_Providers(ProviderManager.getInstance());

  String host = "web.vlivetech.com";                   //getText(R.id.host);                                 
     String port = "5222";                                                             
     String service = "web.vlivetech.com";              // getText(R.id.service);                                      
     String username ="has12345";                      //  getText(R.id.userid);                                          
     String password = "123";                         // getText(R.id.password);                                           

     // Create a connection
         ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                 new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
         connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
         ServiceProviders.Register_Providers(ProviderManager.getInstance());
         try {
             connection.connect();
             Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
             connection.login(username, password);
             Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

             // Set the status to available
             Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
             connection.sendPacket(presence);
         } catch (XMPPException ex) {
             Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
             //MainActivity.setConnection(null);
         }

//         CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest xmlns='naseebprofile' group='Overview and Background' action='buildprofile'></questionrequest>");
//           // CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest  xmlns='profile' from='1' to='10' />"); 
//            // set the type
//             iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
//             iq.setTo("web.vlivetech.com");
//             //iq.setFrom("test@hassaan/Smack");
//
//
//             connection.sendPacket(iq);
//         <!-- IQ For retrieving auto matches -->


         CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<automatches xmlns='naseebautomatch' action='automatch'></automatches>");
//       CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<successstory xmlns='naseebsuccess' action='allstories'></successstory>");
//       CustomIQ iq=new CustomIQ("<questionrequest  xmlns='profile' from='1' to='10' />"); 
//       set the type
        iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
        iq.setTo("web.vlivetech.com");
        //iq.setFrom("test@hassaan/Smack");


        connection.sendPacket(iq);
             PacketFilter filter1 = new IQTypeFilter(IQ.Type.RESULT);
           ((Connection) connection).addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
              public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                  CustomIQ iq = (CustomIQ) packet;

                      Log.i("gotresult", iq.toXML());

                      payload_data = iq.getPayload();
                      while(iq.getPayload() != "" || iq.getPayload() != null){              }
                      payload = iq.getPayload();
                  try {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ParserResult.class));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                      //ParserResult pr = new ParserResult();
                      /*pr.setPayload(payload);
                      pr.start_parsing();
                      payload = pr.getPayload();*/

              }

           }, filter1);



  return null;
 }


 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     int a;

     try {
         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i.setClass(context,ParserResult.class));
//  Intent i = new Intent(NewTask.this,ParserResult.class);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private String getText(int id) {
         EditText widget = (EditText) this.findViewById(id);
         return widget.getText().toString();
     }

  private EditText findViewById(int id) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }




@Override
public void sort(Intent arg0, List<ActivityResolveInfo> arg1,
        List<HistoricalRecord> arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

text here:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: connection.NewTask
E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient$1$1.run(XMPPClient.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
```

Comment: i have write this class name in menifest and error is classdefnotfound

Comment: Post your manifest and the full error log

Comment: ^ and with it, what you use to build your application, how you package it, if the missing class is actually inside your project (and not in an external project) and check the contents of your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my menifest:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabs_example_practice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient"
            android:label="XMPPClient" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.android.xmpp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="adapters.ParserResult1"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_parser_result" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="adapters.OptionsParser"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_parser_result" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="adapters.ParserResult"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_parser_result" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.android.xmpp.Connection"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_connection" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="connection.NewTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="connection.Connection_Create"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_connection" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.android.xmpp.Success"
            android:label="@+string/title_activity_success" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabs_example_practice.MainActivity"
            android:label="@+string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabs_example_practice.signup"
            android:label="@+string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabs_example_practice.login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity><activity
            android:name="com.example.tabs_example_practice.splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This should be added to the question, not as an answer.